# Cannot fetch data from two tables having one to many relationship using Asp.Net MVC 5, Entity Framework 6, AngularJS and OracleDB

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework Database First approach to retrieve data from two Models using ASP.NET MVC 5 and AngularJS. The models are as follows:
**Course Model**

```
public partial class COURSE
{
    public short COURSEID { get; set; }
    public string TITLE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> CREDITS { get; set; }
    public short DEPTID { get; set; }

    public virtual DEPARTMENT DEPARTMENT { get; set; }
}
```

**Department Model**

```
 public partial class DEPARTMENT
{
    public DEPARTMENT()
    {
        this.COURSEs = new HashSet<COURSE>();
    }

    public short DEPTID { get; set; }
    public string DEPTNAME { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<COURSE> COURSEs { get; set; }
}
```

**DBContext:**

```
public partial class StudentEntities : DbContext
{
    public StudentEntities()
        : base("name=StudentEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<SAMPLESTUDENT> SAMPLESTUDENTs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<STUDENTMANAGEMENTUSER> STUDENTMANAGEMENTUSERs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<COURSE> COURSEs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DEPARTMENT> DEPARTMENTs { get; set; }
}
```

**CourseController.cs**

```
public class CourseController : Controller
{
    IGenericRepository<COURSE> repository = null;

    public CourseController()
    {
        this.repository = new GenericRepository<COURSE>();
    }

    public CourseController(IGenericRepository<COURSE> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // GET: /Course/
    [NoDirectAccess]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetAllCourses()
    {
        List<COURSE> courseList = (List<COURSE>)repository.GetAll();
        return Json(courseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**GenericRepository.cs**

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private StudentEntities db = null;
    private DbSet<T> table = null;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        this.db = new StudentEntities();
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }

    public GenericRepository(StudentEntities db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return table.ToList();
    }

    public T GetById(object id)
    {
        return table.Find(id);
    }

    public void Update(T obj)
    {
        table.Attach(obj);
        db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        table.Add(obj);
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        T existing = table.Find(id);
        table.Remove(existing);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**AngularJS CourseController**

```
app.controller("courseController", function ($scope, courseService) {

GetAllCourses();

function GetAllCourses() {
    var getCoursesData = courseService.getCourses();
    getCoursesData.then(function (course) {
        $scope.courses = course.data;
    }, function () {
        alert('Error in getting course records');
    });
};
```

});

app.service("courseService", function ($http) {

```
this.getCourses = function () {
    return $http.get("/Course/GetAllCourses")
};
```

});

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div ng-controller="courseController">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
        <div class="well bs-component">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td><h2><b>Course Information </b></h2></td>
                    <td style="padding-top:20px">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Course" class="form-control" ng-model="searchCourse">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-condensed">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Title</b></td>
                    <td><b>Credits</b></td>
                    <td><b>Department</b></td>
                    <td><b>Action</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="course in courses | filter:searchCourse">
                    <td>
                        {{course.TITLE}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{course.CREDITS}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{course.DEPARTMENT.DEPTNAME}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*<span ng-click="editStudent(student)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</span>*@
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't identify what's the problem. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: assign DEPTID  as foreign key in Course Model class.  add attribute  'Foreign("DEPTID")'  about 'public virtual DEPARTMENT DEPARTMENT { get; set; }
'

Comment: I am using Database First approach. If i change the model, after updating the model from database the changes will be revert back.

Comment: From firebug stacktrace:                                                                             System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.COURSE_A27164420A524FD16E4AAB972BF10B496612AD1BEA52050EA7AC4213338000E0'

Comment: show ur ApplicationDbContext

Comment: My Dbcontext is already listed above

Answer (score 0):

create a db context and change the `GatAll` method to

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return context.DEPARTMENTs.Include(x => x.COURSEs).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the GetAllCourses() method like below :

```
public JsonResult GetAllCourses()
    {
        List<COURSE> courseList = (List<COURSE>)repository.GetAll();
        var collection = courseList.Select(x => new { 
            courseId = x.COURSEID,
            title = x.TITLE,
            credits = x.CREDITS,
            deptId = x.DEPTID,
            deptName = x.DEPARTMENT.DEPTNAME
        });
        return Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and it works like a charm